# How do I fix the Ubuntu Software Center with gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad?

Tags: software-center, gstreamer

I can't update files or get new files. I think the problem is gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad.
Here's the message I get in Ubuntu Software Center:

"New software can't be installed, because there is a prolem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?"

I then I go in a loop when it asks to "repair," I say yes with authentication, and then it says "Requires installation of untrusted packages. This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources."

If I hit "ok," I go in the loop, starting with "New software can't be installed...."
If I hit "repair," I get the same selections again: "ok" and "repair." 
When I click on "details" it just says gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad.

What do I do? I've looked on the web and tried some sudo apt get type commands. Nothing works.

Thanks,

Van

Comment: I just reinstalled Ubunutu 13.04. Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you should have a app called software-properties-(gtk-kde).desktop.
Don't know why this has not been ported to gnome-control-center... I think in kde it exists in there(or equivalent).
Anyhow you should activate the source categories.. (you are allowed to install propietary software in Ubuntu)...
Or you can do it in ubuntu-software-center via a menu... cant remember exact name... Software Package Settings or so)